# What's the difference between spark.eventLog.dir and spark.history.fs.logDirectory?

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, what is the difference between the event log directory and the history server log directory?

```
spark.eventLog.dir hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.fs.logDirectory hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
```

Answer (score 24):

`spark.eventLog.dir` is to generate logs while `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` is the place where Spark History Server finds log events.

From the official documentation of Apache Spark:

> `spark.eventLog.dir` is the base directory in which Spark events are logged, if spark.eventLog.enabled is true. Within this base directory, Spark creates a sub-directory for each application, and logs the events specific to the application in this directory. Users may want to set this to a unified location like an HDFS directory so history files can be read by the history server.

See [spark.eventLog.dir](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-ui).

> `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` is for the filesystem history provider, the URL to the directory containing application event logs to load. This can be a local file:// path, an HDFS path hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs or that of an alternative filesystem supported by the Hadoop APIs.

See [spark.history.fs.logDirectory](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#spark-configuration-options).

Comment: Should they always be the same?

Comment: Yes, per the documentation found at [Spark Monitoring](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

"The spark jobs themselves must be configured to log events, and to log them to the same shared, writeable directory. For example, if the server was configured with a log directory of hdfs://namenode/shared/spark logs, then the client-side options would be: spark.eventLog.enabled true spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs"

Comment: They can be different, otherwise there would not be 2 variables.  Per my understanding, if `spark.eventLog.dir=dir1` while `spark.history.fs.logDirectory=dir2`, then events of current spark are written to dir1, while  history server reads data from dir2 (maybe from another spark install). That is to say, the history server is not dependent on current spark install, you can point to any folder contains history data (*.lz4 files).