# spark history server in yarn mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Can someone help in understanding the clear difference between 
`spark.eventLog.dir` and `spark.history.fs.logDirectory`?

Also please relate these properties to `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` and `mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir`

Please don't paste documentation as the response :)

I have already gone through the below link, but could not understand.
[What's the difference between spark.eventLog.dir and spark.history.fs.logDirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001248/whats-the-difference-between-spark-eventlog-dir-and-spark-history-fs-logdirectoy)

Answer (score 1):

As the linked post says,

`spark.eventLog.dir` is to **write** logs while `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` is the place where Spark History Server **reads** log events.

In certain scenarios, these could be different - for example, some external, periodic job could move the files being actively written into the history location

The Spark log directories should be separated from YARN and MapReduce history server